# Recursive function for depth-first search

Tags: python, search, depth-first-search

Could someone help me with this recursive function I wrote for a depth-first search.

```
Path = [start]
Visited = Path

def DFS(start, end, Path, Visited):
    for i in neighbors(start):
        if i == end:
            Path.append(i)
            return Path
        else:
            if i not in Path and i not in Visited:
                path = Path.copy()
                path.append(i)
                Visited.append(i)
                return DFS(i, end, Path=path, Visited = Visited)

Path = DFS(start, end, Path=Path, Visited = Visited)
```

Somehow the `Path` is a `NoneType` object. I don't understand why.

Comment: `start` is never given a value in the code you show, neither is `end`. Please provide a [mcve]!

Answer (score 2):

Your code only returns a value when it finds an end node. If it does not find the end node in the neighbors of the start node, then it returns nothing, which is equivalent to returning None in Python. That's why you get a NoneType object.

Try this code:

```
Path = [start]
Visited = Path

def DFS(start, end, Path, Visited):
    for i in neighbors(start):
        if i == end:
            Path.append(i)
            return Path
        else:
            if i not in Path and i not in Visited:
                path = Path.copy()
                path.append(i)
                Visited.append(i)
                result = DFS(i, end, Path=path, Visited = Visited)
                if result is not None:
                    return result

Path = DFS(start, end, Path=Path, Visited = Visited)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your function continuously explore the neighbors until it finds the target node or exhausts all possibilities. If the target node is not found, it will return None.

```
def DFS(start, end, Path, Visited):
    for i in neighbors(start):
        if i == end:
            Path.append(i)
            return Path
        else:
            if i not in Path and i not in Visited:
                path = Path.copy()
                path.append(i)
                new_visited = Visited.copy()
                new_visited.append(i)
                result = DFS(i, end, Path=path, Visited=new_visited)
                if result is not None:
                    return result
    return None
```